# How to post an md file on Jekyll website?

Tags: jekyll

I want to post an md file on a Jekyll website to use as an example page. E.g. I want "example.md" to be present on the web page. But of course any .md file I put in my source gets turned into an html page. I thought maybe in the _config.yml file there might be a way to exclude a particular .md file but still have it available on the site. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be sufficient to make the Markdown file into a Gist on Github? Then you can use the [Gist Tag](https://github.com/chamerling/jekyll-plugins/blob/master/gist_tag.rb) plugin like so:

```
{% gist 7056459 example.md %}
```

I believe it is also possible to enclose the markdown portion of the page in an HTML tag like a `div`, and the parser skips it. So you can try that as well.

Comment: Gist is probably not going to work in this particular case. Your second thought was interesting though. I experimented around and found that all I had to do was put a space character at line 1 column 1 (or anything really to prevent the first 3 characters from being "---" and the parser skipped it. Unless a better solution comes along, I'm going to start the document with !--- and add a comment to remove the exclamation mark. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a plain markdown file that you want to store on your website without it being processed by Jekyll make sure that the file doesn't have YAML front matter. Files without front matter are copied over verbatim by Jekyll when the site is processed.

This might work better than the above answer simply because you don't have to add a comment or anything else to get Jekyll to do what you want.